# Overlay area chart on a baseline

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to develop plots for multiple counties with statewise numbers as my baseline. The X-axis is time and Y-axis is a metric - %change with respect to baseline.

Here is a sample chart - The area in blue is the county under consideration. The black line shows the statewide numbers which is the baseline

[image]

How do I achieve something similar in matplotlib? Are there any reference docs for me to try out on sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) with the upper axis limit as the second y value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [1,2,3,4]
county = [3,2,4,5]
state = [3,1,3,4]

ax.set_ylim(0, 6)
ax.plot(x, state, color='k')
ax.fill_between(x, county, 6, ec='#1f77b4ff', fc='#1f77b444')

plt.show()
```

[image]